# Speaker Test Connundrum

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa

In Ubuntu, I was messing with pulseaudio settings after I had a small issue, when I found I no longer had sound or any devices showing in Settings-->Sound. I uninstalled then re-installed pulseaudio as well as alsabase and all seems well now with audio restored.

The only exception is with the Settings-->Sound GUI, where the 'Test Speakers' test no longer produces any sound, despite showing a 'smiley'. I can reproduce this sound test in terminal with `speaker-test -t wav -c 2`, so it's not a big issue. But it would be good to be able to restore this test to the Sound Settings GUI. Any ideas why it's not working there and how to fix, please?

Comment: Try a reboot if you can. Maybe it's lost somewhere...

Comment: Already tried rebooting. Same issue.